# EmEditorによるwebページの文字列取得

Tags: emeditor

EmEditorで特定サイトの文字を丸ごと取得することは可能でしょうか？
たとえば、このサイトだと、クチコミなども含めて、数ページになるのを一機に取得できるかです。

https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B08R9GYRQG/

機能として出来るのか、そうしたことはできないのかだけでも教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 特定のサイトに行って、全テキストを取得ということは、具体的には、そのサイトを表示しているブラウザをアクティブにして、Ctrl + A、Ctrl + C を押してクリップボードに貼り付け、EmEditor に戻って、Ctrl + V (貼り付け) という動作を行えばいいのでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。1ページだけで済む場合だとオール選択、コピー→貼り付けでもたいして手間はかかりませんが、上記のアマゾンの商品ページのようにレビューのページ数が数十ページ有るとスクロールして貼り付けするにも数分かかる作業です。そこで、たとえば2000くらいのレビューがあるアマゾンの商品ページでも一発でEmEditorで取得できないでしょうか？という質問になります。現段階でその機能が無くてもマクロの構築で実現は可能でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: アドレスから関連の文字列を取得する機能です。以下の場合ですと数十ページのレビューが続いています。これを一発で取得できないでしょうか？マクロを書いてもらうのはたいへんと思いますので、何々のメソッドを使えば出来ますみたいな回答で頂けますと幸いです。https://www.amazon.co.jp/EIZO-EV2480-BK-1920%C3%971080-%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC-%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A2IPS/product-reviews/B08R9GYRQG/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews

Comment: つまり、ウェブ サイトで、[次のページ] などと書かれたリンクをクリックして、各々のページの全テキストをコピーして貼り付けるという作業を行いたいということですね? 1つのページだけならできると思ったのですが、リンクをクリックして複数のページをまとめるという作業になると、かなり複雑になると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。おっしゃっている要約のとおりです。これと関連する質問なんですが、そこで連続クリップボード機能が重要になります。アマゾンみたいな大規模サイトだとリンクのパターン自体は正規表現でパターン化できると思いました。そこで連続クリップボードで特定のリンクを辿って、とりあえず一度全部取得する。もしくは、HTMLのタグごと全部取得する。→そのあとで必要な文字列だけ正規表現とかで抽出するというのがいけると考えたのです。スクレイピングと同様のことがEmEditorでいけると思います。連続クリップボードは溜め込まなくても自動でEmEditorに貼り付けてくれる機能があれば実質的に無限の連続クリップボード機能になると思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: v20.7 beta 2 (20.6.902) でクリップボード履歴の機能を強化していますのでお試しください。 https://jp.emeditor.com/forums/topic/emeditor-v20-7-beta-2-20-6-902/ また、これは質問とは関係の無い内容ですので、直接メールしてください。

Comment: イメージとしては、この動画みたいな感じです。https://youtu.be/ehv0aKhfZoY?t=157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

標準状態の EmEditor から直接、任意の web page へのアクセス手段はありませんが、
プラグインやマクロで機能を拡張できるので、出来るようにすることは可能です。
実用性は低いのですが実証用のマクロを作ってみました。

url2txt.jsee

```js
#title="url -> text"

/*
    目的の url, ASIN, ISBN どれかを、文字列選択かクリップボードへコピーして起動。
    ・url ならば、テキストだけ抜き出してアウトプットバーへ出力。
    ・ASIN,ISBN-10,ISBN-13(978) ならば、amazon からテキスト化してレビューページも保存、
      保存先は現在開いているドキュメントと同じディレクトリ、
      アウトプットバーへ、タグジャンプ用のリンクを出力。
    ・どちらも汎用のテキスト変換処理なので精度は低い。

    テストページ
    https://www8.cao.go.jp/chosei/shukujitsu/gaiyou.html        UTF-8 国民の祝日について - 内閣府
    https://eco.mtk.nao.ac.jp/koyomi/yoko/                      Sift_JIS  暦要項 - 国立天文台暦計算室
    http://weather.goo.ne.jp/earthquake/index.rdf               RSS 地震情報 - goo天気
    https://news.yahoo.co.jp/rss/topics/top-picks.xml           RSS Yahoo!ニュース・トピックス - 主要
    400339481X                                                  ISBN-10 ウィーナー サイバネティックス――動物と機械における制御と通信 (岩波文庫)
    978-4003394816                                              ISBN-13 ウィーナー サイバネティックス――動物と機械における制御と通信 (岩波文庫)
*/

 var AmazonReviewLimit = 30;    // 取得ページ数上限
 var Amazon_foreign = true;     // 外国のレビューを有効にする

 var f_Review = true;           // レビュー保存
 var DL_Root = document.Path;   // 保存場所


function netGet( url, agent ){
    var res = {};
    res.body = "";
    res.code = "";
    try {
        var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP");    // Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0
        xhr.open( "GET", url, true );
        if( agent ){
            xhr.setRequestHeader( "User-Agent", agent );    // "" は xhr が受け付けない、" " だと、空の文字列("") になる
        }
        xhr.send();
        for( var rty = 1000; xhr.readyState != 4 && rty > 0; --rty ){ xhr.waitForResponse(100); }
        if( xhr.readyState == 4 ){
            res.code = xhr.status;
            res.status = xhr.statusText;
            res.bytes = xhr.responseBody;
            if( xhr.status == 200 ){ res.body = xhr.responseText; }
        } else {
            xhr.abort();
            alert( "Error abort" );
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert( "Error (" + e.number + ") " + e.name + " : " + e.message + " )" );
    }
    return res;
}

// txt化 簡易処理、<pre> 等未対応
function htm2txt( buff ){
    buff = buff.replace( /\n/g, " " );

    var m = buff.match( /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/i );
    var title = (m != null && m.length > 1)? m[1] : "";

    buff = buff.replace( /<!--.*?-->/mg, " " );
    buff = buff.replace( /<head[\s>].*?<\/head>/i, " " );

    buff = buff.replace( /<script[\s>].*?<\/script>/gi, " " );
    buff = buff.replace( /<noscript[\s>].*?<\/noscript>/gi, " " );
    buff = buff.replace( /<style[\s>].*?<\/style>/gi, " " );

    buff = buff.replace( /&#x([\dA-F]+);/ig, function( c0, c1 ){ return String.fromCharCode( parseInt( c1, 16 ) ); } );

    buff = buff.replace( /&nbsp;?/gi, " " );
    buff = buff.replace( /\s+/g, " " );

    buff = buff.replace( /<\/(div|p|h\d|tr|ol|ul|li|pre|title|item|description|pubDate|entry)\b>/gi, "\n" );    // 段落 等
    buff = buff.replace( /<br(\s*|\b[^>]*)>/gi, "\n" );

    buff = buff.replace( /<.*?>/g, " " );
    buff = buff.replace( /\s+$/gm, "\n" );

    buff = buff.replace( /&lt;?/gi, '<' ).replace( /&gt;?/gi, '>' ).replace( /&quot;?/gi, "\"" ).replace( /&apos;?/gi, "'" );

    buff = buff.replace( /&amp;?/gi, '&' );
    return [buff, title];
}

// amazon review 抜き出し 専用
function review2txt( buff, page ){
    buff = buff.replace( /\n/g, " " );

    var m = buff.match( /<title>(.*?)<\/title>/i );
    var title = (m != null && m.length > 1)? m[1] : "";

    buff = buff.replace( /<!--.*?-->/mg, " " );
    buff = buff.replace( /<head[\s>].*?<\/head>/i, " " );

    buff = buff.replace( /<script[\s>].*?<\/script>/mgi, " " );
    buff = buff.replace( /<noscript[\s>].*?<\/noscript>/mgi, " " );
    buff = buff.replace( /<style[\s>].*?<\/style>/mgi, " " );

    var revList = "";
    var rev_count = 0;
    for( var no = 1; true; ++ no ){
        var m = buff.match( /^.*? id="[\w\d]+-review-card" .*?>(.*?>)違反を報告<\/a>(.*)$/i );
        if( m == null || m.length < 2 ) break;
        buff = m[2];
        if( ! Amazon_foreign && m[1].match( / id="customer_review_foreign-/ ) ) continue;
        ++ rev_count;

        imh = {};
        m[1] = m[1].replace( /<img alt="カスタマー画像" src="\s*(https:\/\/images-na\.ssl-images-amazon\.com\/images\/I.*?)\s*".*?>/ig,
            function( cap0, cap1 ){
                if( imh[cap1] == true ){ return " "; }
                imh[cap1] =  true;
                var href = cap1.replace( /\._SY88\./, '.' );
                return "<br> " + href + " ";
        } );

        var txt = htm2txt( m[1] );
        revList += txt[0];
        revList += "\n<------------ " + ('  '+page).slice(-3) + " - " + (' '+no).slice(-2) + " ------------>\n";
    }

    return [revList, title, rev_count];
}

// amazon review page 巡回
function amazonReviews( asin, rootDir, f_Review ){
    amazon_agent = " "; // Amazon は標準の User-Agent だと弾かれる。
    var htm = netGet( "https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/" + asin, amazon_agent );
    if( htm.body == "" ){ return }

    var txt = htm2txt( htm.body );
    var fpath = rootDir + "\\" + "amazon_" + asin + ".txt";
    var topFpath = "" + fpath;

    editor.NewFile();
    document.Encoding = 65001;
    document.UnicodeSignature = false;
    document.write( txt[1] + "\n\n" + txt[0] ); // title + body
    document.selection.StartOfDocument();
    document.Save( fpath );
    OutputBar.writeln( fpath + "(1):" );

    if( f_Review ){
        var next_url = "";
        for( var no = 1; no <= AmazonReviewLimit; ++ no ){
            Sleep( 1 );
            htm = (next_url == "")?
                netGet( "https://www.amazon.co.jp/product-reviews/" + asin + "/?pageNumber=" + no + "&reviewerType=all_reviews", amazon_agent ) :
                netGet( next_url, amazon_agent );
            if( htm.body == "" ){ break }
            next_url = "";
            var f_next = (htm.body.search( / class="a-last".*?<a\s+href="(.*?)".*?>次へ</im ) >= 0);
            if( f_next ){
                next_url = RegExp.$1.replace( /^.*?\/(product-reviews\/.*)$/, "https://www.amazon.co.jp/$1" );
                next_url = next_url.replace( /&amp;/g, "&" );
            }
            txt = review2txt( htm.body, no );
            if( txt[2] != 0 ){
                fpath = rootDir + "\\" + "amazon_"  + asin + "_" + ('00'+no).slice(-3) + ".txt";
                editor.NewFile();
                document.Encoding = 65001;
                document.UnicodeSignature = false;
                document.write( txt[1] + "\n\n" + txt[0] );
                document.selection.StartOfDocument();
                document.Save( fpath );
                document.close();
                OutputBar.writeln( fpath + "(1):" );
            } else {
                OutputBar.writeln( "Page: " + no + " Review Count == 0 : Amazon_foreign = " + Amazon_foreign );
            }
            if( ! f_next )  break;
        }
    }
    OutputBar.writeln( "Done." );

    editor.OpenFile( topFpath );
}

function bytes2utf8( bytes, enc ){
    var fh1 = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    fh1.Type = 1;
    fh1.Open();
    fh1.Write( bytes );
    fh1.Position = 0;
    fh1.Type = 2;
    fh1.Charset = enc;
    rval = fh1.ReadText();
    fh1.Close();
    return rval;
}

function url2txt( url ){
    var htm = netGet( url );
    if( htm.body == "" ){ return }
    if( /<meta[^>]*\bcharset[\s="']+(Shift_JIS|EUC-JP)/im.test( htm.body ) ){
        switch( RegExp.$1.toLowerCase() ){
        case "shift_jis":   htm.body = bytes2utf8( htm.bytes, "SJIS" );     break;
        case "euc-jp":      htm.body = bytes2utf8( htm.bytes, "EUC-JP" );   break;
        }
    }
    var txt = htm2txt( htm.body );
    OutputBar.writeln( txt[1] + "\n\n" );   // title
    OutputBar.writeln( txt[0] );            // text
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MAIN

    OutputBar.Clear();
    OutputBar.Visible = true;

    var stropt = document.selection.Text.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );
    if( stropt.length == 0 ){
        stropt = clipboardData.getData( "Text" ).replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );
    }

    if( stropt.search( /^https?:.*/ ) >= 0 ){
        url2txt( stropt );
        Quit();
    }

    if( stropt.search( /^B0[A-Z\d]{8}$/ ) >= 0 ){   // ASIN
        amazonReviews( stropt, DL_Root, f_Review );
        Quit();
    }

    if( stropt.search( /^[\s\dX-]+$/ ) >= 0 ){      // ISBN-10
        var isbn = stropt.replace( /[\s-]/g, '' );
        if( isbn.length == 10 ){
            var chk = 0;
            for( var i = 0; i < 9; ++ i ){
                chk += parseInt( stropt.charAt(i) ) * (10-i);
            }
            chk = (11 - (chk % 11)) % 11;
            chk = (chk == 10)? 'X' : String( chk );
            if( chk == stropt.charAt(9) ){
                amazonReviews( stropt, DL_Root, f_Review );
                Quit();
            }
        }
    }
    if( stropt.search( /^[\d\s-]+$/ ) >= 0  ){      // ISBN-13 978
        var isbn = stropt.replace( /[\s-]/g, '' );
        if( isbn.length == 13 && isbn.substr(0,3) == '978' ){
            var chk = 0;
            for( var i = 0; i < 13; ++ i ){
                chk += parseInt( isbn.charAt(i) ) * (2*(i&1) + 1);
            }
            chk = (10 - (chk % 10)) % 10;
            if( chk == 0 ){
                for( var i = 3; i < 12; ++ i ){
                    chk += parseInt( isbn.charAt(i) ) * (13-i);
                }
                chk = (11 - (chk % 11)) % 11;
                isbn = isbn.substr(3,9) + ((chk == 10)? 'X' : String( chk ));
                amazonReviews( isbn, DL_Root, f_Review );
                Quit();
            }
        }
    }
    OutputBar.writeln( "*** '" + stropt + "' ***" );    // 対象外
```

---

- 仕様
  Amazon は [www.amazon.co.jp](http://www.amazon.co.jp) の日本語ページだけに対応。「カスタマー画像」など日本語のメッセージから処理しているため。
- 改変
  2021/04/09 amazonReviews() バグ改善、Review.bat は精度が低いので削除。
  Amazon_foreign 追加、false で国内からのレビューに限定。

Comment: ご回答頂き、ありがとうございます。使わせて頂いてまたコメントでお伝えさせて頂きます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。取得できました。現在の仕様は日本語レビューのみの優先取得になりますでしょうか？外国語レビューの場合は省略される仕様になってますでしょうか？外国語も翻訳ソフトで見たいので追加できれば幸いです。コメントのオンオフで日本語レビューか外国語レビューか、その両方を取得するか選べる仕様に出来ましたら幸いです。コードを書いていただきありがとうございます。

Comment: バグってたので修正しました。Amazonの現行のページ構成なら可能な場合がある位に考えてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまく取得できました。またよろしくお願いいたします。