# EmEditorをウェブスクレイピングとして使うことは可能でしょうか？

Tags: python, web-scraping, emeditor

EmEditorをウェブスクレイピングとして使うことは可能でしょうか？

たとえば事例として、EmEditorのリファレンス
http://www.emeditor.org/ja/index.html

裏ワザ的な方法としては、サイトをまるごと保存するソフトで、全部一式ダウンロードする。
リファレンス関連のページを全部結合→整形→ひとつにする

この方法もありますがやり方としては、簡易ではないです。
そのため、
リファレンスページを何らかの登録をすると、自動収集ウェブスクレイピングツールにしてファイルをダウンロードか、記事をコピペ収集してひとつに蓄積、ひとつのファイルとして保存するという手順です。

目星としてつけている方法としては、Pythonライブラリにウェブスクレイピングの記事があるので、PythonライブラリとEmEditorの組み合わせでできそうな感じですが、最短で出来る方法でいいのがありましたらお願いいたします。

具体的にマクロを書いてもらうのはたいへんと思いますので可能かどうか教えて頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: EmEditor がいくら高機能といえど、あくまで「テキストエディタ」です。web スクレイピングに関しては Python や Ruby などの「プログラミング言語」で十分実現可能かと思いますが、敢えてテキストエディタでスクレイピングを実現しようとしているのはなぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ヘルプファイルは EmEditor 自身でダウンロード出来ます。

EmEditor の [ヘルプ]->[設定]を「ローカルヘルプ」にして、
その段階でローカルに無かったら更新のチェックを行えば自動でダウンロードされると思います(確認はしていません)、
そして EmEditor上から Ctrl-F1 でローカルのヘルプファイルを開くことが出来ます。
少なくとも通常のアップデートでヘルプファイルもアップデートする設定にしていれば自動でダウンローダされます。

標準で `C:\ProgramData\Emurasoft\EmEditor\Help\emeditor_ja.chm` 辺りに本体があるのでこれのショートカットを作るのも良いでしょう。

更にブラウザで見たかったら、適当な場所にディレクトリを掘って

```
> mkdir D:\Editor\EmEditor\help\doc
> hh.exe -decompile D:\Editor\EmEditor\help\doc C:\ProgramData\Emurasoft\EmEditor\Help\emeditor_ja.chm
```

とすれば、`D:\Editor\EmEditor\help\doc\index.htm` をブラウザで直接開くことが出来ますし、
そのディレクトリをタブレットにでも入れればいつでも見られるようになりますね。

---

### ※ chm の元データが手に入ったので自分用に編集してみる。

- まず最初のハードルは hhc.hem の入手です、現在、MS のサポート期間が過ぎて MSのサイトからの入手は出来ません、
  HTML Help Workshop を、アーカイブサイトか VC++6.0とかのパッケージから発掘するとかしてください。
- decompile したときのディレクトリ設定に合わせて説明すると doc/ に次のファイルを SJIS で保存します

# emeditor_ja.hpj

```
[OPTIONS]
Compatibility=1.1 or later
Compiled file=emeditor_ja2.chm
Contents file=EmEditorHelpContents.hhc
Default Window=titlewindow
Default topic=index.htm
Display compile progress=No
Error log file=Compile.Log
Full-text search=Yes
Index file=EmEditorHelpIndex.hhk
Language=0x411 日本語 (日本)
Title=EmEditor ヘルプ
Default Font=MS UI Gothic,11,138
Auto Index=Yes
Binary Index=Yes
Flat=No

[WINDOWS]
titlewindow="EmEditor ヘルプ","EmEditorHelpContents.hhc","EmEditorHelpIndex.hhk","index.htm","index.htm",,,,,0x21420,,0x386E,,,,,,,,0

[FILES]
images/bg-header.png
```

- 変更したい場所を、自分用に書き換える。
  一例として、 doc/macro/document/document_close.htm
  `<h6>Copyright` の前の行に下を挿入。

```html
<h3>参照</h3>
<h5><a href="document_saved.htm">Saved プロパティ</a></h5>
```

doc の上のディレクトリ D:\Editor\EmEditor\help に

# compile.bat

```
@Echo off
cd doc
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe" emeditor_ja.hhp
pause
```

これを実行して、成功すれば、doc 内に emeditor_ja2.chm が作成されます。

- 差分を管理して、本体の Help file が更新されたらそれに差分を当てる。

---

2021/04/04 chm 編集 追加。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。EmEditorとPythonかRubyなどのライブラリを使ってウェブスクレイピングができないかと考えております。

Comment: 質問で挙げている「EmEditorのリファレンスページ」はあくまで例であり、"任意の"ページを EmEditor でスクレイピングできないか、という質問のように見えます。

Comment: 同様な質問が https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74883/ にもありますのでも参照してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ヘルプファイルをダウンロードしてHTMLで全部結合できました。約56000行ありました。丁寧に教えて頂きありがとうございます。