# マクロで処理した文書を別名で保存した場合に元のファイルを自動で保存しないで閉じたいです。

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
EmEditorでファイルを元のファイルから、マクロで生成して新しく別名保存したときに作成の元のファイルを保存せずに閉じるにはどう書けばよろしいでしょうか？

マクロで処理した文書を別名で保存した場合に元のファイルを自動で保存しないで閉じたいです。

document.close();
これだと、いちいち「変更を保存します」かという確認画面が出ます。

editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4120);
これだと開いている文書すべてが閉じるため確認画面が出ずにマクロで処理した元のファイルだけ閉じてしまいたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.Saved プロパティの設定で確認なしに close 出来ます。

```js
document.Saved = true;
document.close();
```

ヘルプファイルが不親切な感じもするのでその編集法も追加しておきます。
[EmEditorをウェブスクレイピングとして使うことは可能でしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74968/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまく動作しました。